# Get final/sync selected result in checkbox in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

suppose i have a todo app. in another table i save userid and todoids like:

```
user-----todo_ids
1-------------2,6,5,8
2------------6,8,5,9
```

when load user wise todo, i checked based on their todo_ids. Problem is that when i deleted a todo, it does not not sync when update the user todo!

https://jsfiddle.net/Fawel/1ej8tomn/

There you will see that in selected property value is :selected:[1,2,8]
But in todo list i don't have any value with id 8. When i save console also print with all checked with 8 !
And if i save this, i will be saved with extra id 8 which todo is deleted!
How can i get synced and final value when click save button. 
What i want is that when i click on saveorupdate button i must have got with existed ids list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's should returns you are waiting for

```
saveOrUpdate: function(){
      const vm = this
        console.log(
      this.todos.filter(
        (t)=>{return vm.selected.includes(t.id)}
      ).map((t)=>{return t.id})
      );
    }
```

Comment: Your code is working on js fiddle. But when i get data from api and split it, i got result ilike this :
`  ["4", "5", "6", "10", "1", __ob__: Observer] `
Then filtered result return null! @Maxim

Answer (score 1):

Create a computed method to get existing ids in your to do list, and use that to filter out non-existed values in selected array:

```
...
computed: {
    todoIds: function() {
        return this.todos.map(function(item) {
            return item.id;
        })
    },
    filteredSelected() {
        return this.selected.filter(function(item) {
            return this.todoIds.includes(item);
        })
    }
},
method: {
    saveOrUpdate: function() {
        this.filteredSelected; // This is what you need
    }
}
```